# Why can't I see my entire image with the iPhone 3?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

So I'm pretty close to finishing up my little project and I'm trying to make sure that my app is compatible with the iPhone 3 and 4...but this is really stumping me.  I'm using the open source CCPickerview code posted by hm50 some time ago (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10160).  It works GREAT for the iPhone 4, but not at all in the iPhone 3 simulator.  I think the problem is somewhere here in the implementation.  I can sort of see what's happening when I incorrectly leave the -hd tag on the image.  It appears that the image is getting cut clean in half once in non-retinal mode, and I can't say I'm an expert enough to identify why.

```
-(void)makePages {
    CCSprite *overlay = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"overlay-hd.png"];
    CGSize s = CGSizeMake(overlay.contentSize.width, overlay.contentSize.height);
    self.contentSize = s;

    CCLayerColor *backLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:(ccColor4B){248,250,251,255} width:self.contentSize.width height:self.contentSize.height];
    backLayer.position = ccp(-self.contentSize.width/2, -self.contentSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:backLayer];

    self.baseLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:(ccColor4B){150,150,150,0} width:s.width height:imgSize.height * numPages];

    for (int i=0; i < [arrayPages count]; i++) {
        CCNode* n = [arrayPages objectAtIndex:i];
        n.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2 + i * (imgSize.height + padding)); 
        [baseLayer addChild:n];
    }

    baseLayer.position = ccp(-s.width/2, -s.height/2 - s.height * currentPage);
    [self addChild:baseLayer];

    overlay.position = ccp(0, 0);
    //overlay.opacity = 0;
    [self addChild:overlay];

    rect = CGRectMake(self.position.x - s.width/2, self.position.y - s.height/2, s.width, s.height);

    [self moveToPagePosition];
}

- (void) visit 
{
    if (!self.visible)
        return;

    glPushMatrix();

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CGRect scissorRect = rect;

    ccDeviceOrientation orientation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] deviceOrientation];
    switch (orientation) 
    {
        case kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            break;
        case kCCDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            scissorRect.origin.x = size.width-scissorRect.size.width-scissorRect.origin.x;
            scissorRect.origin.y = size.height-scissorRect.size.height-scissorRect.origin.y;
            break;
        case kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        {
            float tmp = scissorRect.origin.x;
            scissorRect.origin.x = scissorRect.origin.y;
            scissorRect.origin.y = size.width-scissorRect.size.width-tmp;
            tmp = scissorRect.size.width;
            scissorRect.size.width = scissorRect.size.height;
            scissorRect.size.height = tmp;
        }
            break;
        case kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            float tmp = scissorRect.origin.y;
            scissorRect.origin.y = scissorRect.origin.x;
            scissorRect.origin.x = size.height-scissorRect.size.height-tmp;
            tmp = scissorRect.size.width;
            scissorRect.size.width = scissorRect.size.height;
            scissorRect.size.height = tmp;
        }
            break;
    }

    glScissor(scissorRect.origin.x*2, scissorRect.origin.y*2,
              scissorRect.size.width*2, scissorRect.size.height*2);

    [super visit];

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

[Screenshot](http://i1151.photobucket.com/albums/o624/mae1778/screenshot.jpg)

If I move the scroll over to the right, more of it shows up, but I really don't want it over there.  Can any of you brilliant objective-c gurus help me out with this?

EDIT:

After further investigation, the issue is without a doubt:

```
rect = CGRectMake(self.position.x - s.width/2, self.position.y - s.height/2, s.width, s.height);
```

If I make it

```
rect = CGRectMake(self.position.x - s.width*2.05, self.position.y - s.height/1.48, self.contentSize.width*1.3, self.contentSize.height*.48);
```

It works just fine...but I don't think this solution is very elegant and it should be based on the overlay picture size.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a CCPickerView too, you can find it on github. https://github.com/fidgetware/CCPickerView.  It works with both low-res and hi-res images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing double-resolution images are being used on the older devices, which will be twice the size they should be.

You need to check the `-scale` property of the window's screen (or use `[UIScreen mainScreen]`), and choose the correct (retina or not) image based upon that.

Comment: I'll definitely check that, but shouldn't the entire image still show up?  When I remove the -hd tag, absolutely zero shows up and I'm wondering if that clipping effect is what's responsible

Comment: Okay.  Best I can tell, the content size is being correctly displayed once I remove the -hd tag.  The problem is the image never shows up.  When I leave the -hd tag, and hard code the content size to be half, it also disappears.

Comment: You may need to create your own low-resolution version of the image. Perhaps the `CCPickerview` you talk about was only developed with retina graphics in mind.

Comment: I did have a separate low resolution version of the image, but I suspect you are right about retina graphics being in mind when it was written.  I probably just need to sit down and study what the rect equation is doing.  I know it's suppose to be making a box around the overlay.png, and I think scissorRect uses it to mask off the picker.  I'm just not sure why it matters what mode the phone is in.